# How Do I register a Target (which is not on AWS) to Network load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-elb

I have an SMTP server running (I have its ip address) but when I try to register it as a target to NLB I get the following error:

*An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the RegisterTargets operation: The Availability Zone is required for IP address 'X.X.X.X' because it is not in the VPC.*

The SMTP is not running on AWS so I do not have its AZ, but I know its IP and hostname. I am using target-type as "ip" for the NLB.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

> using target-type as "ip" for the NLB

It must be **private IP** address, not public. So you either have to setup a VPN between AWS and your SMTP server, or migrate your SMTP to AWS.